# Apache Cassandra node return different data

Tags: cassandra, nosql

We have 5 nodes Apache Cassandra cluster with replication factor 2.
All health monitoring commands like 'nodetool status' or so show no error.
But nodes not really in sync.
Same request on different nodes may return different values.
More over same request on same node might return different values
[image: screenshot]

Question - is there a way except 'nodetool repair' to force synchronizaiton over nodes?

Is there a way to make all data fully replicated on over all nodes (increase replication factor) on running production cluster?

Answer (score 2):

You need to set `CONSISTENCY LOCAL_QUORUM;` on the CQLSH (& on your application most likely) prior to running your query. Also, a replication factor of `2` is just not efficient as RF/2+1 of `2` is `2`. So, even if one of the replica holding the data is down, your application will face downtime. It is better to adjust the RF (at the keyspace level) to be `3` to begin with as you can tolerate `1` replica failure when you're dealing with `LOCAL_QUORUM` consistency level.

Also, ensure your repairs are running correctly in this cluster.